# What is the difference between targeting mui class '&.className ' and '& .className'?

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to create a local override for a native select component, and the only way it worked is by doing the following?

```js
{
'& .Mui-disabled': {
    color: grey[400],
    WebkitTextFillColor: grey[400],
},
'&.Mui-disabled': { 
  '&:before': {
    color: grey[400],
},
'&:after': {
   color: grey[400],
},
},
```

What is the difference between the two variations? I wanted to nest under the first class but could not get the needed behavior?

Comment: The space denotes the selector following the space is a descendant of the current target (&); no space is the current target with the selector class.

Comment: @Phix could you show me a better version to implement the current example ?

Comment: @Phix so I can target all the children of the class, while the other will target the class directly.